# Matlab update variable outside the timer

Tags: matlab, user-interface, timer

I am struggling trying to find a simple solution to this Timer issue.
I would like the timer to update the entire workspace so I could re-use the updated value to be display on a GUI.

Here is the Matlab timer,

```
handles.server_timer = timer('TimerFcn',@timer_server,'UserData',handles);
start(handles.server_timer);
```

it calls the function timer_server.m (bellow) :

```
function timer_server(obj,~)

    handles=obj.UserData;  % Get User Timer input data

    % GET DATA & GENERATE/UPDATE OBJECT
    [handles.SERVER,handles.CLIENT,handles.OBJ] = Lib_Zig.zigREAD(handles.SERVER,handles.CLIENT,handles.OBJ );

    obj.UserData=handles; % Set User Timer output data

end
```

Currently the handles is being updated inside the TIMER but not in the WORKSPACE so the updated HANDLES is not accessible/saved within the rest of the GUI.

I could use GLOBAL VARIABLE but from what I hear it is not very efficient and could slow down the program.

I could also update the GUI from inside the timer but I think it would make more sense to have 2 timers. One to handle the Network data flow and an other to handle the GUI interface.

Would anybody have an idea on how to get the timer to update the HANDLES within the entire WORKSPACE at every period ?

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use handles and guidata in my GUI's so I might be wrong here - but I suspect you are missing a call to `guidata`:

```
guidata ( uiObject, handles )
```

This is needed to make sure that the handles is updated in the core figure -> so that all callbacks etc.. can pick it up.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is I don't have a uiObject in the Timer function

Comment: Do you not have one (somewhere) inside the `handles` structure?

Comment: I guess I could set it to any graphic obj ? but I don't know if it is very elegant.

Comment: *I dont think `guidata` and `handles` are elegant at all!! ;)*  I suspect it would be best to pass the figure handle - but yes you should be able to provide any GUI object...

Comment: How do you create a GUI without handles ?

Comment: That's another question completely!!  Which I couldn't do justice answering a comment - in short create objects directly through `uicontrol` and store in `appdata` - see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/matpihome/matlab-gui-framework) for how I do it!